# Проверка существования объекта

Tags: c++, c++builder

```c++
TListBox * lbx2; //обьявил локально
if (??????) { //если компонент такой сущесвует (lbx2) или если выделена память
  for (int j(0); j < lbx2 - > Items - > Count; j++) {
    tstn[j] - > Release();
    Application - > ProcessMessages();
  }
  lbx2 - > Clear();
} else { //либо создаем такой компонент
  lsbx = new TStringList(GridLayout2);
  lbx2 = new TListBox(GridLayout2);
}
```

Вот что подставить там где знаки вопроса?

Comment: `lbx2 != nullptr`?

Answer (score 1):

```
TListBox * lbx2 = 0;
//...
if (lbx2 != 0)
```

Comment: Для указателей не рекомендуется использовать литерал `0`. Современный *C++* рекомендует использовать `nullptr`. Или, хотя бы, макрос `NULL`.

Comment: nullptr это уже C++0x, NULL - могли переопределить define-ом. Так что нет - надо использовать 0 в старом добром С++

Comment: @Sublihim когда `NULL` кто-то переопределяет это уже вредительство. Вы же не будете отказываться от `true`/`false` только лишь по той причине, что кто-то может написать `#define true false`. `NULL`, как и `nullptr` проще искать в тексте, чем обычный `0`.

Comment: я ориентируюсь на http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#null почему бы не доверять? Ответ на http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176989/do-you-use-null-or-0-zero-for-pointers-in-c вполне себе говорит об этом

Comment: У Вас две ссылки по сути одинаковые. А второй ответ на enSO по сути подтверждает мою точку зрения. Но изначально я хотел возразить только на фразу `NULL - могли переопределить define-ом.`. Не использовать `NULL` только лишь по этой причине - довольно странно.

Comment: @alexolut, да, ссылки по-сути одинаковые. В свое время про 0 я почерпнул как-раз у Струструпа. Сейчас нашел ссылку на обсуждение на en stackoverflow. Собственно в своей практике всегда использовал 0, как-то на проблемы не натыкался (процессору плевать же что там NULL или 0) Но соглашусь, что мой опыт касался С++03 и в основном windows.

Comment: Да не спорьте, горячие финские парни! Напишите просто и незатейливо - `if(lbx2)`...

Answer (score 1):

```
TListBox * lbx2 = NULL;
if (lbx2) { //если компонент такой сущесвует (lbx2)или если выделена память
```

Comment: лучше вообще `0` использовать, если это C++

Comment: @Sublihim Не лучше. Возможно существование платформ, где нулевой адрес валидный.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176989/do-you-use-null-or-0-zero-for-pointers-in-c